# Simple Registration very slow response times

Tags: registration, ee5, simple-registration

Recently rolled out the latest version of Expression Engine (5.1.2) and upgraded our PHP version to 7.2 and noticed a massive drop in the response times from our signup forms the using Simple Registration addon.

We used to receive a response in under a second, now it takes 10+ seconds to register a user or return an error message.

I'm wondering if this is just a compatibility issue with the latest version of EE (or php) or if it's something else?

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Worth mentioning that the members table is very large, but I've tested other plugins and they don't have the same problem. Would like to continue using Simple Registration if there is a solution to this problem, as it has functionality that I have been unable to find in other member addons.

Comment: Hi, how many members do you have and what functionality are you using in SR when they signup (ie. assign member groups)?

Comment: Hi, we have approx 800,000 members. With regards to functionality, we have 2 custom fields when members sign up and we have the majority of Expression Engines default required fields turned off (confirm email, username etc). I believe the member group is currently assigned by default (people going into pending and then member once they have confirmed).

Comment: Hi, I've tested on 5.1.2 and 5.1.3 now, it seems to work fine and I don't see a reason why it should be slow with 800k members. But it's hard to debug locally - could you please email me at bjorn@lastfriday.com and we can take it from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been a problem with my server config running the queries slowly, not with Expression Engine or the Simple Registration plugin. It's odd that this problem occurred when upgrading to EE 5.1.2, but I have recently moved to a new hosting provider and speeds have increased dramatically.